# Tailwind pseudo-element after inserting content image

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I wanna ask something about pseudo-element using tailwind, so before going through into my main problem I wanna show my code using `CSS`

```
.text-location {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.625rem;
}

.text-location::after {
  content: url('image/arrow-down-icon.svg'); <= example image
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

it's working and nothing something wrong when I used in `CSS`, but when I'm going through using `tailwind` the `content` is not showing anything, any wrong with my code? Or I must do something different what I have been made? I hope anyone can help and tell me where I made the mistake...Thank you before and have a nice day, bellow my code:

```
<label class="font-poppins text-sm font-light leading-[0.875rem] text-[#969696] flex gap-[1.625rem] after:content-[url('image/arrow-down-icon.svg')] after:inline-block after:h-full after:w-full">Location</label>
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `item-center` class here and use `text-black` to make them look similar. You have to use custom fonts as `popins` is not supported by default.
You can refer [here](https://blog.avneesh.tech/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-tailwindcss)

Below is my code

https://play.tailwindcss.com/0wks3noHUe

Comment: thank you for answer my question, but sir my own image still didn't show on my webpage, I already check if the path of my image is wrong but is not, any else suggest sir?

Comment: Instead of image you can use icon like font-awesome

Comment: okei sir thanks for all, I already done with my problem, once more thank you

Comment: Glad I am able to help you

Answer (score 9):

You can define your content in the **tailwind.config.js**

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      content: {
        'arrowDownIcon': 'url("../src/arrow-down-icon.svg")',
        'arrowUpIcon': 'url("../src/arrow-up-icon.svg")',
      },
      fontSize: {
...
```

You can render it using the following className. Make sure to include an **inline-block** and **width**.

```
<label className="after:content-arrowDownIcon after:inline-block after:w-8">Learn More</label>
```

You can also apply a hover state like this **hover:after:content-arrowUpIcon**

```
<label className="hover:after:content-arrowUpIcon after:content-arrowDownIcon after:content-arrowBlack after:inline-block after:w-8">Learn More</label>
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to where this is documented in more detail? The Tailwind docs (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content#customizing-your-theme) only describe the config file, not how to actually use the classes. And for some reason I can't get it to work, here's an example (the first p tag contains the after:content-test) https://play.tailwindcss.com/bAuEk88sIH

Comment: @Lesik2008 there is something wrong with your setup, you can also test it using inline TailwindCSS using `after:content-['test']` in your `<p class="after:content-['test'] after:inline-block after:w-8">Description<p>`